# Creating hyperlinks in TeXmacs

Tags: formatting, texmacs

In TeXmacs, I'm trying to insert hyperlinks that link to urls with the command `\hlink` and then I fill out the appropriate name and the url. But when I try to open the link in TeXmacs it yields the error:

> The file  cannot be loaded or created

How do I correctly have these hyperlinks open up in my default browser when I click on them?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you get `\hlink` from? Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem? That way we can give you answers more readily.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right command? TeXmacs is a "what you see is what you mean" software program. I last tried it nearly ten years ago, but I don't remember ever entering "TeX-like" commands.... @Werner -- I'm not sure you can provide an MWE for TeXmacs files: they are not `.tex` files (though they can be exported to various formats).

Comment: "TeXmacs allows you to enter LaTeX commands directly from the keyboard as follows. You first hit the \-key in order to enter the hybrid LaTeX/TeXmacs command mode. Next you type the command you wish to execute." It's a shortcut for Insert -> Link -> Hyperlink.

Comment: I can insert symbols in Word with TeX syntax. This doesn't make questions on that process on-topic for this site.

Comment: Please consider supporting the proposed creation of a TeXmacs SE site here: https://area51.stackexchange.com where such kind of questions can be discussed.